# Blogger template syntax (Label RSS feeds)

Tags: html, xml, templates, blogger, label

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to create an RSS feed URL in the Labels Gadget within google blogger?

I need to have and RSS feed link after each label search link.

I have checked these pages:

http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46888
[http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47270](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46888)

and cannot find any solution.

I could hard link the feed URLs but then would have issues if the labels change.

Here's the code for this section in the Labels gadget:

```
  <b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
    <p>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:label.url'>
        <span expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection'>
          <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url'>
            <data:label.name/>
          </a>  
        </span>
      <b:else/>
    <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url'>
          <data:label.name/>
        </a>
      </b:if>
      <b:if cond='data:showFreqNumbers'>
        <span dir='ltr'>(<data:label.count/>)</span>
      </b:if>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:label.url'>
        <span style='margin-left:1em;'>
        <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url'>
          <img src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-XqVwdzsG73g/T9A44Jq3OPI/AAAAAAAAAA0/RTd9pAVWy9s/s1600/rss-icon.gif' style='vertical-align:middle;'/>
        </a>
        </span>
      <b:else/>
        <span style='margin-left:1em;'>
    <a expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:href='data:label.url'>
          <img src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-XqVwdzsG73g/T9A44Jq3OPI/AAAAAAAAAA0/RTd9pAVWy9s/s1600/rss-icon.gif' style='vertical-align:middle;'/>
        </a>
        </span>
      </b:if>
    </p>
  </b:loop>
```

As you can see from the code sample the Label name is linked to a search URL for any posts with that label attached to them.

I would like the RSS image ICON that I have created to link to the RSS feed URL for that particular label.

Thanks a heap in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

OK thanks for the attention everyone ;)

I've figured it out:

```
<a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name'>
<img src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-XqVwdzsG73g/T9A44Jq3OPI/AAAAAAAAAA0/RTd9pAVWy9s/s1600/rss-icon.gif' style='vertical-align:middle;'/>
</a>
```

Fairly simple: it just involved building the url for each label being specified by the 'data:label.name' bit in the url.

Cheers